# Can I get location of website?

Tags: php, javascript, geolocation, location

Let me explain by an example:-

let say http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2012/sep/18/pentagon-stops-training-partnering-afghan-troops-b/ is the URL which was submitted by an user, now what I need is a method in php or javascript or in any other web-scripting language which can give me the location corresponding to above url, like in which country this website is hosted,
as in this case result should be "United States". It is done by many websites like http://www.site24x7.com but I need a code to do that

Comment: So what have you tried? Any initial thoughts on how you might tackle the problem?

Comment: You can get this info from WHOIS API's like http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/ - they aren't free though

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, get the hostname from the url then use gethostbyname() to get the IP, then get some info about the IP from a whois site.

```
<?php 
$url  = 'http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2012/sep/18/pentagon-stops-training-partnering-afghan-troops-b/';

$host = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_HOST);
$ip = gethostbyname($host);
$info = get_ip_info($ip);

$result = array('host'=>$host, 'ip'=>$ip, 'info'=>$info);

print_r($result);
/*
Array
(
    [host] => www.washingtontimes.com
    [ip] => 38.118.71.70
    [info] => Array
        (
            [host] => theconservatives.com
            [country] => United States
            [country_code] => USA
            [continent] => North America
            [region] => Virginia
            [latitude] => 38.9687
            [longitude] => -77.3411
            [organization] => Cogent Communications
            [isp] => Cogent Communications
        )

)
*/
echo $result['info']['country']; //United States

function get_ip_info($ip = NULL){
    if(empty($ip)) $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/ip-address-locator.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array('ip'=>$ip));
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    preg_match_all('/<i>([a-z\s]+)\:<\/i>\s+<b>(.*)<\/b>/im',$data,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
    if(count($matches)==0)return false;
    $return = array();
    $labels = array(
    'Hostname'          => 'host',
    'IP Country'        => 'country',
    'IP Country Code'   => 'country_code',
    'IP Continent'      => 'continent',
    'IP Region'         => 'region',
    'IP Latitude'       => 'latitude',
    'IP Longitude'      => 'longitude',
    'Organization'      => 'organization',
    'ISP Provider'      => 'isp');
    foreach($matches as $info){
        if(isset($info[2]) && !is_null($labels[$info[1]])){
            $return[$labels[$info[1]]]=$info[2];
        }
    }

    return (count($return))?$return:false;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is built into PHP. Use the gethostbyname method to lookup the IP Address and then use a free API to look up the location (such as MaxMind)
Also there's a parse_url method in PHP to help you get the actual domain name from a URL. Do not use shell_exec when there are safer methods available.